# wordpress change themes location

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Usually all the wordpress themes are uploaded and saved over the server say http://example.com/wp-content/themes/ . I am developing a plug-in to change this path to something like http://xyz.com/themeFolder/ . So i have to develop such a functionality where my wordpress installation will be on one server and the themes and plug-ins folders will be on another server.

Any help, will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance to all the genius people out there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Version 2.6`, you can move the `wp-content directory`, which holds your *themes, plugins, and uploads*, outside of the WordPress application directory.

Set `WP_CONTENT_DIR` to the full local path of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content' );
```

Set `WP_CONTENT_URL` to the full `URI` of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content');
```

[SOURCE](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/moving-my-wp-contentthemes-directory?replies=3)

Do not forget to check [THIS](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) page as well.